# Why allocationSize was not considered in H2 spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

For my spring boot, I created the following query in data.sql file.

```
INSERT into ROOM( id, title, room_size) values (1, 'Green', 20);
INSERT into ROOM( id, title, room_size) values (2, 'Blue', 50);
```

now for my Room Entity, I created the below class

```
@Entity(name = "room")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Room {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_room_id")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_room_id",allocationSize = 1)
    Long id;

    String title;

    @Column(name = "room_size")
    Long roomSize;

    @CreatedDate
    LocalDateTime createdOn;
}
```

but when I tried to add a new Room it is giving me a ConstrainViolation exception as it is trying to add a room with id 1 again ignoring to check *allocationSize=1*

How to solve this?

Comment: When you use an identity column or column with a sequence, you shouldn't try to insert your own IDs into it. All values need to be generated, otherwise generated values may conflict with values specified explicitly.

Comment: @EvgenijRyazanov what could be the alternative? keep AUTO?

Comment: `IDENTITY` should be better than `SEQUENCE` and with it you will be able to insert your data without specifying `id` column (`INSERT into ROOM(title, room_size) values ('Green', 20);`).